# How can I catch an error without using try/except?

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

Is there something that I could use to catch errors in python without using a try/except?

I'm thinking of something like this:

main.py

```
from catch_errors import catch_NameError
print(this_variable_is_not_defined)
```

catch_errors.py

```
def catch_NameError(error):
    if type(error) == NameError:
        print("You didn't define the error")
```

The output would be:

```
You didn't define the error
```

Instead of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(this_variable_is_not_defined)
NameError: name 'this_variable_is_not_defined' is not defined
```

Comment: You could take a look at `sys.excepthook`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook

Edit: what is your motivation for this though?

Comment: With a mechanism like this, it would be unclear where execution resumes after exception handling. Attempts to resume execution at the location where an exception was thrown have historically lead to awful, buggy messes, and pretty much no one designs exception handling systems that way any more.

Comment: @jackarms OpenCV's Python API has very non-descriptive errors. I want to create a simple Python module that catches the errors, then raises another error that is descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

It *can* be done by creating a context manager, but it gives questionable benefit over an explicit `try:except:`. You will have to use the `with` statement, so it will be clear where behavior will change. In this example, I am using [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager) to do this, which saves the tedium of creating a class with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def IgnoreNameErrorExceptions():
    """Context manager to ignore NameErrors."""
    try:
        yield
    except NameError as e:
        print(e)  # You can print whatever you want here.

with IgnoreNameErrorExceptions():
    print(this_variable_is_not_defined)
```

This will output

```
name 'this_variable_is_not_defined' is not defined
```